# runing command on startup

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, bootloader, startx

I need to execute this command on the RASPBERRY PI bootup

```
cd RPi_Cam_Web_Interface && ./install.sh
```

and also follows dual ENTER keys with 5 seconds interval for each.

Comment: Why do you want to run an install script at every startup? You would normally install just once!

Comment: its an pi-Cam web interface , which shows live preview from the picam. but it is not starting at BOOT , even though the auto start is enabled

Comment: What happens when you enter 'cd RPi_Cam_Web_Interface' then './start.sh' ?

Comment: when entered  ./start.sh it  just skips to the next line without executing anything

Comment: This is a typical X/Y problem. Rather than asking about the workaround you invented, explain your original issue (pi-Cam web interface not starting at boot?) and see what alternative solutions are possible.

Answer (score 0):

thanks People, i finally made it work by using  this below command:
     **\cd /home/pi/RPi_Cam_Web_Interface && ./install.sh**
and saved this as an Script and finally  mentioned this script at the botom line  of     **"sudo nano .bashrc"**
and now when i boot my pi,the software is installed freshly.

Comment: Seems like this would only run when you log in, not when you boot.

Comment: Please accept your answer with a click on the tick on the left side. This will finish the question and it will not pop up again months for months.

Answer (score 0):

Try edit /etc/rc.local described in https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md
IT May helps.

Comment: Please add so much information so that the answer can stand of it's own and the URL is just a reference.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways to execute a boot command. I use the [rc.local](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md) file. `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` Add your shell command before the `exit 0`

for entering two enter keypress you can something along the lines of

```
cd RPi_Cam_Web_Interface && ./install.sh
echo | <yourfinecommandhere>
sleep 5s
echo | <yourfinecommandhere>
```

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Comment: I think the OP has misunderstood how RPi-Cam-Web-Interface works.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you could also use `sudo crontab -e` and just add a command with the absolute path (`/usr/bin/foo`).
To run a command at boot and reboot in the background (so it doesn't prevent pi from continuing boot), add `@reboot /usr/bin/foo&`

Comment: No comment on why this is a downvoted method?

Answer (score -1):

Add theat command in .bashrc file and it will do